# Git: How do I calculate the number of times a line has changed?

Tags: bash, git, code-metrics

I'm trying to get the churn, or the number of times a line of code has changed. I've seen various approaches to do this with files, but how can I do it with a single line?

Using git log and numstat we can do something like

```
git log --numstat --pretty="%H" --after=2022-05-01
```

It's useful, but it does it at the file level. How can I do it at the line/code block level?

Comment: *how can I do it with a single line?* Write a many-line program, and then invoke it using a single line. (In short: you can't, until you write your own program. Consider using `git blame` repeatedly to follow modifications to each line.)